# How can I terminate my maven build based on results from the exec-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven-2

I am using the exec-maven-plugin to run a windows batch script.  The batch script runs in a separate process from my maven build.  When my batch script throws an error, how can I stop my maven build with an error response?

Please find the maven exec plugin version details below:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
```

Also, I am using maven 2.2.1

Comment: Is this a kind of integration test? Or what are you trying to achieve? Can you show the complete pom?

Comment: I am trying to run a simple Java Jar, if the jar returns an error code, then I want my maven build to stop.

Comment: Why do you need to start a java jar which should control the build in any kind? What purpose is behind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the exec-maven-plugin to fail the build you have to throw an exception from the jar you are calling.  The plugin will not fail the build based on a non-zero return code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try throwing an exception in my jar rather than call System.exit(someErrorCode);

Comment: Hi @gregwhitaker why not? Can you elaborate on that?
Geography guy, have you solved it that way?
I'm having a similar issue, I have _exec-maven-plugin_ running a _.cmd_ script which calls _.sql_ scripts, I can get the sql error and I do _Exit 1_ but maven just keep going to the next execution... Just realised now how old this is.. :(